# Change log level on runtime for containers

Tags: docker, go, logging, kubernetes

im using [`logrus`](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus) for logging for out applications which run on K8S
we have env variable which we can set the `log-level` and change it when we restart out application
our applications is running with docker containers on k8s
Now we want to change the log-level on runtime, i.e. don’t restart the container and change it 
when it’s running and with this we can change it from `error` to `debug`, I think this 
is legitimic request but didn’t find any reference or any open source which doing this, any idea?

```
package logs

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

const (
    AppLogLevel = “APP_LOG_LEVEL"
    DefLvl = "info"
)


var Logger *logrus.Logger


func NewLogger() *logrus.Logger {

    var level logrus.Level
    lvl := getLogLevel()
    // In case level doesn't set will not print any message
    level = logLevel(lvl)
    logger := &logrus.Logger{
        Out:   os.Stdout,
        Level: level,
    }
    Logger = logger
    return Logger
}

// use from env
func getLogLevel() string {
    lvl, _ := os.LookupEnv(AppLogLevel)
    if lvl != "" {
        return lvl
    }
    return DefLvl
}

func logLevel(lvl string) logrus.Level {

    switch lvl {
    case "debug":
        // Used for tracing
        return logrus.DebugLevel
    case "info":
        return logrus.InfoLevel
    case "error":
        return logrus.ErrorLevel
    case "fatal":
        return logrus.FatalLevel
    default:
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("the specified %s log level is not supported", lvl))
    }
}
```

I know how to change the log level but I need a way to infuance the logger to change the level

Answer (score 3):

As a general Un*x statement, you cannot change an environment variable in a process after it has started.  (You can **setenv**(3) your own environment, and you can specify a new process's environment when you **execve**(2) it, but once it's started, you can't change it again.)

This restriction carries through to higher levels.  If you've `docker run` a container, its `-e` option to set an environment variable is one of the things you have to delete and recreate a container to change.  The `env:` is one of the many immutable parts of a Kubernetes Pod specification; you also can't change it without deleting and recreating the pod.

If you've deployed the pod via a Deployment (and you really should), you can change the environment variable setting in the Deployment spec (edit the YAML file in source control and `kubectl apply -f` it, or directly `kubectl edit`).  This will cause Kubernetes to start new pods with the new log value and shut down old ones, in that order, doing a zero-downtime update.  *Deleting and recreating pods like this is totally normal* and happens whenever you want to, for example, change the image inside the deployment to have today's build.

If your application is capable of noticing changes to config files it's loaded (and it would have to be specially coded to do that) one other path that could work for you is to [mount a ConfigMap into a container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume); if you change the ConfigMap contents, the files the container sees will change but it will not restart.  I wouldn't go out of my way to write this just to avoid restarting a pod, though.

Answer (score 0):

First off, understand this should happen on the **application** level. I.e. it's not something that Kubernetes is supposed to do for you.

That being said, you could have your application checking an environment variable's value (you are already doing this), and depending on what that value is, it can set the application's log-level. **In other words, let the application code poll an environment variable to see if it has changed.**

You can inject environment variables like Shahaf suggests, but that requires you to `exec` into the pod, which may not always be possible or good practice.

I would suggest you run `kubectl set env rs [REPLICASET_NAME] SOME_ENVIRONMENT_VAR=1`.

All of this being said, you need to consider *why* this is important. Kubernetes is built under the principle that "*pods should be treated like cattle, not pets*". Meaning when a pod is no longer useful, or out of sync, it should be terminated and a new one, that represents the code's current state, should be booted up in its stead.

Regardless of how you go about doing what you need to do, you REALLY shouldn't be doing this in production, or even in staging.

Instead let your app's underlying environment variables set a log-level that is appropriate for that environment.

Comment: Thanks, why we shouldn't be this in prod? sometimes when you re-start a pod you dont see the error in the new pod instance ...

Comment: It's just not good practice to have to restart pods in a production environment to change the log-level. 
However, your prod environment should be monitoring / logging the bare minimum for you to be able to at least get an idea of what's wrong. But maybe that's not a realistic scenario?

Comment: Bottom line is, you shouldn't *have* to remote onto a server to change an application's log-level. 
The log-level should be something static for each environment, so that you know it's not been tampered with. Especially in a clustered environment where logs have a tendency to disappear due to pods dying. How else are you going to have any form of confidence in what has broken?

Comment: if customer is reporting a bug I can ask him to run some script/command to change the log level and in this way I've precise info of what happining in the pod, otherwise restart the pod will not reflect this info as it was before the restard due to many things such is user interacation with the app etc

Comment: Why would you ever ask a customer to run a script to find out about information in **your** production environment? 

If that's something that you need to debug an issue on your end, you have bigger problems than you are letting on.. :/

Answer (score -1):

You can run the command `kubectl exec -it <container_name> bash` and use the command line inside the container to change the environment variable .
You can do it by running the command `export LOG_LEVEL=debug` or `export LOG_LEVEL=error` inside the container.

Comment: Thanks, in this way I was able to change the env, but the log-level doesnt changed...

Comment: Seems like the log level will be updated only when you initialise a new logger. So you are dependant on restarting the container. Maybe add a mechanism that gets the log level from the env var for each log.